# Sqlite execution order

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

Im currently developing an app with phonegap. Therefore im forced to work with Sqlite on the DB side. 
My problem is that brackets aren't accepted so I don't know how to execute one statement before another one. 
The query that I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emojiname 
FROM (SELECT emojiname, timestamp
      FROM table 
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC) 
ORDER BY timestampt DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

I tried to figure it out on my own but I couldn't.

I'd very much appreciate your help.

Cheers, 
Valentin

Comment: Is it ok a name of column is **timestamp** at one place and **timestampt** on the other?

Comment: oh im sorry about that. its the same variable

Comment: I mustn't say sorry. just fix your code! ;-)

Comment: That doesnt have to do anything with the actual code. This is the MySql query that would fetch the right information. The actual problem is to convert this query to sqlite because in sqlite one cant use brackets so i cant execute the inner Select statement before the outer one.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

This must work

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.emojiname 
FROM (SELECT emojiname
      FROM `table` 
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as t
LIMIT 25
```

and even this must work too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emojiname
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: The issue was that i couldn't execute the select statement before the distinct statement.
But i was able to solve that by creating a temporary "viewtable" and do 2 separate sql statement.